# How to define a function that checks if the parameter is string in TypeScript 2.0

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Say I have a function that checks if a parameter is string defined like this :

```
function isString(value: any): boolean {
    return typeof value === 'string' || value instanceof String;
}
```

Now when I use this function with typescript 2.0 control flow analysis I would expect the following to work :

```
function foo(param: string|Foo) {
   if(isString(param)) {
      // param is not narrowed to string here
   } else {
      // param is not narrowed to Foo here 
   }
}
```

Is there a different way I could define isString that would make the example if statement narrow the type of param correctly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript has [Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) to help with this.

You can have a [user defined guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function isString(value: any): value is string {
    return typeof value === 'string' || value instanceof String;
}

function foo(param: string | Foo) {
    if (isString(param)) {
        // param is string
    } else {
        // param is Foo
    }
}
```

But in your case you can just use `typeof`:

```
function foo(param: string | Foo) {
    if (typeof param === "string") {
        // param is string
    } else {
        // param is Foo
    }
}
```

If `Foo` is a class then you can also use `instanceof`:

```
function foo(param: string | Foo) {
    if (param instanceof Foo) {
        // param is Foo
    } else {
        // param is string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type needs to use the custom type guard syntax for this to work:

```
function isString(value: any): value is string {
    return typeof value === 'string' || value instanceof String;
}
```